# Create a new addition operator for the Date class

Tags: r, datetime, operators

I'd like to define an addition operation for the  `Date` class, in order to add months, instead that days.

This works:

```
`+.Date`<- function(date,n) seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]
```

Unfortunately it  destroys (masks) the original addition operation based on days.

This works as well:

```
`%+%`<- function(date,n) seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]
```

but it is not specific for the  `Date` class.

One could define a graceful exit.

```
`%+%`<- function(date,n) {
    if (class(date)=="Date") return (seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2])
    else stop("%+% only valid for Date + numeric")
}
```

Anyway  the ideal would be an operation `%+%` defined for `Date`, like in `+.Date`:

```
rm("%+%")
`%+%.Date`<- function(date,n) seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]
```

but:

```
as.Date("2010/1/1") %+% 2
Error: could not find function "%+%"
```

Can you fix `%+%.Date`? Do we have to redefine the class `Date`?

Please, do not suggest some fancy library just to sum a couple of objects. Better to share the ideas in their code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to define `%+%` as well, to make it a generic function:

```
`%+%` <- function(x,y) UseMethod("%+%")
`%+%.Date` <- function(date,n) seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]

as.Date("2010-01-01") %+% 2   # 2010-03-01
1 %+% 1                       # Error
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, just what I was unable to find in the documentation.